# Sending commands to esp8266 from Azure Iot

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266, azure-iot-sdk

I've successfully implemented esp8266 mqtt example found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino-protocol-mqtt/tree/master/examples/esp8266/simplesample_mqtt). My device is connecting and sending data to Azure IOT and then processed using a function. In the example it defines multiple actions using `WITH_ACTION`. Is there any documentation or examples on how to call these actions? I'm currently working off a mac and would prefer to call these actions from a java application if possible.

Answer (score 0):

These actions are implement as direct methods on device. You can call these Direct Method to the device from service back end like this tutorial does:

[Call the direct method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-java#call-the-direct-method)

Set method name and optional parameter. For your esp8266 sample you can set like this:

```
  // Name of direct method and payload.

  public static final String methodName = "SetAirResistance";

  public static final int payload = 10; // Number of seconds for telemetry interval.
```

Comment: Would I need the payload to be a ContosoAnemometer in this case?

Comment: @Jim No need a ContosoAnemometer. Just parameters for the function(if it has) like what I set in my answer.

Comment: @Jim Do you have any problem about this issue?